# Answering Queries on List of Subarrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Given an array A of size N, we construct a list containing all possible subarrays of A in descending order.
Two subarrays B and C are compare by padding zeroes until both are of size N. Then, we compare the two subarrays element by element and return as soon as a point of difference is observed.
We are given multiple queries where given x we have to find the maximum element in the xth subarray sorted according to the order given above.
For example, if the array A is [3, 1, 2, 4]; then the sorted subarrays will be:

[4]

[3, 1, 2, 4]

[3, 1, 2]

[3, 1]

[3]

[2, 4]

[2]

[1, 2, 4]

[1, 2]

[1]

A query where x = 3 corresponds to finding the maximum element in the subarray [3, 1, 2]; so here the answer would be 3.
Since the number of queries are large (of the order of 10^5) and the number of elements in the array can also be large (of the order of 10^5), we would need to do some preprocessing to answer each query in O(1) or O(log N) or O(sqrt N) time. I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I have solved it for when the array contains unique elements, however how could we do this for when the array contains repetitions? Is there any data structure which could help in storing the required information?

Comment: Aren't there supposed to be more of these sub-lists?

Comment: How about just store each subarray's max with it as part of the pre-processing stage?  Getting to the nth subarray is O(1) and getting it's max if precomputed is O(1)

Comment: @danh there will be N*(N+1)/2 subarrays so doing that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Build [suffix array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) in back order for this array (consider it like string)

For every entry store it's length and cumulative count (sum of lengths from the beginning of suffix array)

For query find needed index by binary search for cumulative counts, and get needed prefix of found suffix

For your examples suffixes with cumul.counts are

```
4 (0)
3124 (1)
34  (5)
124  (7)
```

query 3 finds entry 3124 (1<=3<5), and gets `3-1=2-nd` (by length) prefix = `312`

Comment: This won't work when there are repetitions in the array. For example, consider [4, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2]. The subarrays starting with 4 would be ordered like [4, 3, 2] [4, 3] [4, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2] [4, 2, 5, 4, 3] [4, 2, 5, 4] [4, 2, 5] [4, 2] [4] [4]     (Sorry for the lack of readability)

Comment: OK, I see the problem. And don't see reliable method to overcome it yet. Taking common prefix into consideration works for two suffixes, but becomes overcomplicated for many suffixes with common prefixes.

Comment: I was thinking of using some data structure to calculate how many times a prefix occurs in all the suffixes, and then use that information to get the subarray. However, even that would be quite complicated.